# PHPUnit testing coverage help for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, phpunit

Below function we need to cover,

```
function get_assets_list() {
    static $assets;
    if ( ! isset( $assets ) ) {
        $assets = load_asset_file( BUILD_PATH . 'asset-manifest.json' );
        if ( empty( $assets ) ) {
            $assets = array();
        }
    }
    return $assets;
}
```

But unfortunately we can't cover below lines

```
if ( ! isset( $assets ) ) {
        $assets = load_asset_file( BUILD_PATH . 'asset-manifest.json' );
        if ( empty( $assets ) ) {enter code here
            $assets = array();
        }
    }
```

Because when we execute the this function always getting $assets this variable set. So how we can set this variable unset or undefined. So that we can cover those line.

Answer (score 0):

I am executed below,

```
public function test_get_assets_list() {
        static $assets = null;
        // Replace this with some actual testing code.
        $output = get_assets_list();
        $this->assertArrayHasKey( 'block.js', $output );
    }
```

but its not covered below lines

```
if ( ! isset( $assets ) ) {
        $assets = load_asset_file( BUILD_PATH . 'asset-manifest.json' );
        if ( empty( $assets ) ) {
            $assets = array();
        }
    }
```